# How can I split an .hdf file with different layers into different shapefiles containing one layer each using tools of ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, hdf

I have downloaded a file from ftp://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SAN/MOSA/MYD10A1.006/2002.07.04/MYD10A1.A2002185.h24v05.006.2016152140234.hdf but this file contains multiple layers, so I want to split this file into multiple files with each output file containing each layer.

How can I do that in ArcGIS?

Comment: Please edit your question so that "shape file" is not used as a generic term for data source (a *shapefile* is only one specific format)

Answer (score 2):

One can either use the [Extract Subdataset](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/extract-subdataset.htm) tool in ArcGIS or I did the same for a bunch of rasters that I downloaded using the python script below: (Note, I renamed the rasters based on what I needed, which could be avoided)

```
import arcpy,os,re
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\\MODIS Data\\"
out_dir = "F:\\MODIS Data\\EVIData\\"

 rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*")
 count = 1
 for raster in rasters:
    output = str(raster)
    s1 = raster.split('.')[2]
    s1 =s1[1:]
    name = out_dir + raster.split('.')[1] + s1
    print name
```

###Extract the subdataset that you accordingly need to use, here I chose EVI and hence the number is 1

```
arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(raster, name, "1")
```

Comment: Please click on the green tick mark so that this question is marked as answered.